# Android Intermediates error? appcompat-v7 / cfc_tracker:processReleaseResources

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to import a open source project, it works on everyones windows machines but not on mine.

The weirdest thing happens, when I go to build the application everything in intermediates blows up. Specifically items in the styles folder for app compat? Not exactly doing anything with themes..

```
/Users/x/repos/vv/hues/android/cfc_tracker/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.0.0/res/values-v11/values.xml
Error:(47, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(47, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(47, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(47, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
/Users/x/repos/vv/hues/android/cfc_tracker/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.0.0/res/values-v14/values.xml
Error:(17, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(17, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(17, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(17, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
/Users/x/repos/vv/hues/android/cfc_tracker/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.0.0/res/values-v21/values.xml
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Dialog'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
```

The only error I see is...

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':cfc_tracker:processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/x/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

if I run

```
/gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace
```

I get

```
:cfc_tracker:processReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':cfc_tracker:processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/x/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':cfc_tracker:processReleaseResources'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/x/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:66)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:235)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:222)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 47 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/x/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:42)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:780)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder$processResources$1.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.groovy:145)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.groovy:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
        ... 53 more
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/x/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:365)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:40)
        ... 58 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 12.31 secs
```

I'm not sure whats going on. Its a new laptop so its possible that I didn't set a path var correctly

```
 ~/.profile


GRADLE_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/gradle;
export GRADLE_HOME
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

export PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin:JAVA_HOME
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging I found a few talking about the compiled SDK.

THis issue was driving me nuts as on my personal laptop it worked, no problem! However that laptop hasn't been updated in about a month.

The solution was
https://github.com/pnikosis/materialish-progress/issues/6
Use compileSdkVersion 21 and targetSdkVersion 21 without any issue and deploy on sdk 19